# Nginx Logs - No access to /var/log/nginx

Tags: nginx, log

Running Ubuntu 16. I do not have access to `/var/log/nginx`

Is it safe to run a command like this to obtain access?

```
sudo chown -R myusername:www-data /var/log/nginx
```

Comment: If you have sudo access, why not just use `sudo tail -f /var/log/nginx/whatever.log` or `sudo ls /var/log/nginx` to see the content.

Comment: i can't download the logs using Filezilla though

Comment: Ok, so you want to be able to access the logs via ftp/sftp? That's a compeltly different question. Maybe adjust the question then to what you want to accomplish and what the error was.

Comment: ok thanks, will create a new topic then bcs I was also wondering about www-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good idea to change permissions or ownerships of directories within the `/var/log/*`, add your user to the `adm` group or use ACLs, to give your user the necessary permissions.

Comment: Hi I am confused. My user is already in www-data

Comment: @JoannaMikalai What is the output of `ls -ld /var/log/nginx`?

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 2 root adm 4096 Jul 24 06:25 /var/log/nginx

Comment: @JoannaMikalai Updated the answer, with that you can read the logs ;) don't forget that you have to logout and re-login (after adding yourself to `adm` group).

Comment: ok one last question though. In my nginx.conf I have user www-data; - should www-data have access to the nginx log folder for optimal performance or does it not matter

Comment: That question is specific to nginx, I guess you will get a better answer about it at https://serverfault.com/

Comment: @Ravexina Or they can ask me - I maintain nginx in Ubuntu.  Server Fault also requires something to do with business deployments and not end user setups too, which means this isn't necessarily on topic there.

Comment: @JoannaMikalai No the log folder should not be owned or held by `www-data` - the master process of nginx that spawns the unprivileged workers has root access to write to the logs and read config files, beyond that it doesn't have any real use.  It doesn't need `www-data` to access the log files and nor should it need that access.

Comment: @ThomasWard Good to know +1 ;)